# Why do I get "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided." for GET but not PUT for OpenSearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/request-signing.html#request-signing-node) for signing HTTP requests to an Amazon OpenSearch Service using Node.js (version 3 of the AWS SDK for JavaScript).

When I copy the exact sample code and export my `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` of my authorised user, the `PUT index/type/id` request to add an item is successful:

```
201 Created
Response body: {"_index":"products","_type":"_doc","_id":"2","_version":1,"result":"created","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":2,"failed":0},"_seq_no":0,"_primary_term":1}
```

However, when I change the request to instead `GET /_search` endpoint, I get:

```
403 Forbidden
Response body: {"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."}
```

The user is fully authorised against the index:

```
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::**:user/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-user"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:ap-southeast-2:**:domain/mydomain/*"
    },
```

How do I rectify my signature?

Here is my modified code from the above link:

```js
const { HttpRequest } = require('@aws-sdk/protocol-http')
const { defaultProvider } = require('@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node')
const { SignatureV4 } = require('@aws-sdk/signature-v4')
const { NodeHttpHandler } = require('@aws-sdk/node-http-handler')
const { Sha256 } = require('@aws-crypto/sha256-browser')

const region = ''
const domain = ''
const index = 'products'
const type = '_search'
const createBody = (query) => ({
  query: {
    multi_match: {
      query,
      type: 'phrase',
      fields: [
        'tags',
        'name',
        'category',
        'maker'
      ]
    }
  },
  highlight: {
    pre_tags: [''],
    post_tags: [''],
    fields: {
      tags: {},
      name: {},
      category: {},
      maker: {}
    }
  }
})

searchIndex('sh').then(() => process.exit())

async function searchIndex (query) {
  const request = new HttpRequest({
    body: JSON.stringify(createBody(query)),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      host: domain
    },
    hostname: domain,
    method: 'GET',
    path: index + '/' + type
  })

  const signer = new SignatureV4({
    credentials: defaultProvider(),
    region: region,
    service: 'es',
    sha256: Sha256
  })

  const signedRequest = await signer.sign(request)

  const client = new NodeHttpHandler()
  const { response } = await client.handle(signedRequest)
  console.log(response.statusCode + ' ' + response.body.statusMessage)

  let responseBody = ''
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    response.body.on('data', (chunk) => {
      responseBody += chunk
    })
    response.body.on('end', () => {
      console.log('Response body: ' + responseBody)
      resolve(responseBody)
    })
  }, (error) => {
    console.log('Error: ' + error)
  })
}
```

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary my  javascript linter automatically changed that - quotes on the object property name do not effect the request, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Inside the error block - try `console.log(this.request.httpRequest);  console.log(this.httpResponse);`, what do you get?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I added   `}, (error) => {
    console.log('here')
    console.log('Error: ' + error)
  })` but it never logs `here`, it only logs from the preceding block (`response.body.on('end'`). I tried a logging a few variants of what you suggested but they were all `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i also had this issue, using the same tutorial

reading the [docs on request body searches](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/searching.html#searching-dsl), i found it states the following:

> Note The _search API accepts HTTP GET and POST for request body
> searches, but not all HTTP clients support adding a request body to a
> GET request. POST is the more universal choice.

changing my method to `POST` solved the issue for me